# How can I make an OR between validation rules in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need the username to be either `alpha` or `alpha_num`.

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'alpha|alpha_num',
]);
```

Comment: So,what issue are you facing now

Comment: When input is alphanumeric, there's an error saying > username may only contain letters

Comment: I think that it should be done using custom validation rule.

Comment: Just use `alpha_num`, as it covers `alpha` too.

Comment: But doesn't `alpha_num` include `alpha`, so you could just use `alpha_num` for both?

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use alphanum (since apha is a subset of alphanum).

alphanum will validate true when all alpha chars, all numeric chars, or mix of alpha and numeric chars.

If you are wanting to exclude the all numeric possibility (i.e. validate true when all alpha chars or a mix of alpha and numeric chars, but not when all numeric) then you can use a regular expression

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'regex:/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/'
]);
```

But to answer your first question about how to make an OR in validation rules, you will need to make your own custom rule.

Check out the documentation on custom validation rules
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

If it's something you're going to use again you're better off to write a rule. If it's a one time thing then you can put it in a closure.

As an example using a closure, if you wanted to test for alpha with ctype_alpha() and test for alphanumeric with ctype_alnum(), then you could do an OR like

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => [ 
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if( ctype_alpha($value) || ctype_alnum($value)) {
                return $value;
            } 
            return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
        }
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the below validation to solve your issue.

```
$this->validate($request, ['fieldname' => 'regex:/^[\w-]*$/']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'alpha_dash',
]);
```

The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores.

details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-alpha-dash